# can't debug https webpage in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: debugging, https, visual-studio-2017, ssl-certificate

I’m trying to test a website in Visual Studio 2017. However, I get the following error message when I start debugging the website. I believe this has to do with Visual Studio’s SSL certificate. The error message says:

> adding a certificate to the trusted root certificates store failed with the following error: access denied

[image]

And it causes issues downstream when I try to debug a https webpage. The webpage says:

> this page can’t be displayed

[image]

Is there a way to fix this certificate issue with Visual Studio 2017 so that I can debug the https webpage in my website?

Comment: Do you deploy it to the IIS or just run it locally? Not debug your website, how about running with "Start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)"? Please also run your VS as the admin, debug it again.

Comment: Or it is related to the IS Express Self-Signed Certificate:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/

Comment: I run it locally. "Start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)" & run VS as the admin both didn't work

Comment: I can browse to https://localhost:44300/ using Internet Explorer but it does not lead to Certificate error

Comment: Does it have this issue if you update your VS 2017 to the latest version 15.7.1?

Comment: this issue has been fixed by regenerating the certificates and importing them again

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could post your solution as an answer, and then mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours. Have a nice day:)